# Custom JSP TLD involving both Attributes and elements

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tags

I am trying to create a custom TLD for my Spring 3 based application having following format :

```
<prefix:mytag attribute1="myvalue">
    <element>abcd</element>
    <element>abcd</element>
    <action>cancel</action>
</prefix:mytag>
```

For this I am extending **javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport** and defining the property *attribute1* but how can I define the elements ?

My TLD is follows :

```
<tag>
    <description>My custom TLD</description>
    <name>mytag</name>
    <tag-class>mypackage.MyCustomTLD</tag-class>
    <attribute>
        <description>Hold Attribute</description>
        <name>attribute1</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define the elements of tag, they are considered as separate tags.

You need to define tags for each of your sub elements as well. Here is a an example.

```
<app:paramGroup id="edit">
     <app:param id="name" value="attribute"/>
     <app:param id="attId" name="attForm" property="id"/>
</app:paramGroup>
```

In Order to achieve the above functionality you need to define two tags.

```
<tag>
    <name>paramGroup</name>
    <tagclass>com.mycompany.taglib.ParamGroupTag</tagclass>
    <info>
        Param Group Tag used to define the parameters group required for the struts html link
    </info>

    <attribute>
        <name>id</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
</tag>


<tag>
    <name>param</name>
    <tagclass>com.mycompany.taglib.ParamTag</tagclass>

    <bodycontent>empty</bodycontent>

    <attribute>
        <name>id</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>

    <attribute>
        <name>name</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

And here are tag classes, the parent tag instance should be published to context so that the child tags can interact with the parent.

```
public class ParamGroupTag extends BodyTagSupport {

    public static final String NAME = "com.mycompany.taglib.ParamGroupTag";

    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {

        boolean exist = false;

        params = new HashMap();

        // your initialization code

        // Store this tag itself as a page attribute
        pageContext.setAttribute(ParamGroupTag.NAME, this);

        // Continue processing this page
        return (EVAL_BODY_BUFFERED);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the paramter this param object
     * @param paramName Parameter Name
     * @param value     Parameter Value
     */
    public void addParam(String paramName, Object value) {
        params.put(paramName, value);
    }

    /**
     * Clean up the Tag.
     *
     * @exception JspException if a JSP exception has occurred
     */
    public int doEndTag() throws JspException {

        // tag functionality here

        // Remove the Tag from pageContext
        pageContext.removeAttribute(ParamGroupTag.NAME);

        // Continue processing this page
        return (EVAL_PAGE);
    }

}


public class ParamTag extends BodyTagSupport {

    /**
     * Reads the Params and Publishes to ParamGroup
     *
     * @exception JspException if a JSP exception has occurred
     */
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {

        ParamGroupTag paramGroupTag = (ParamGroupTag)
                    pageContext.getAttribute(ParamGroupTag.NAME);

        if (paramGroupTag == null) {
            throw new JspException("ParamTag must be used with in ParamGroup Tag");
        }

        // read the attribtues

        paramGroupTag.addParam(id, value);

        // Continue processing this page
        return (EVAL_PAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you do in endTag instead of doStartTag() ?

Comment: Well you don't need to. You can do it in doStartTag. I copied it from one of my tag source, it needs read the body of the tag, so thats why i did it in endTag. But yeah you can do it in doStartTag.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the response !

Comment: Welcome, And Thanks for for Accepting my Answer :)

Comment: Missed one thing, doEndTag for the parent. We need to clean the context in doEndTag. So that it will not interfere with another ParamGroup Tag.

Comment: Thanks ! for all the help. Appreciate it.